# Evolving lines with mirror effect

Tags: after-effects, animation, after-effects-expressions

I would like to create evolving lines similar to those in this sequence (starting at 0:28):

I know how to reveal lines, but I struggle to make the line moving so smoothly while continuously increasing its width (narrow at the tip and slowly widening).

Could you please give me some tips on how to do this in After Effects? Thanks!

Comment: Should anyone need the same effect, I received quite good advice on CreativeCOW from Mr. Kalle Kannisto: https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/1067004 He said there must be a better way to do this though, so I'm keeping this question open.

Comment: Some of the Animation (but not the Lines of which you speak) is Fractal Zooming (like the 'growing Spades'), for example: https://vimeo.com/12185093 and the Lines look like this (modify): https://youtu.be/w-JG1n_Yeo8 -- I'm hoping someone with far more AE experience can mashup those ideas and form a proper answer for you. Other suggestion is look at Credits and see who did the Graphics, maybe the Graphics House prefers particular Tools. It could be hand drawn animation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 3d Stroke.

The taper parameter should help you.